# srand(time(0)) and rand() are causing a stack overflow error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sorting, random

I'm working on a project for class where I have to implement different sorting algorithms. One of them is a randomized quicksort, but my random number is always set to -800 million even after setting srand and setting a scope of numbers to pick from, causing a stack overflow error.

I've tried everything I can really think of, which isn't much. I tried making a random number generator in another .cpp file and it works fine, it just doesn't work in this context for some reason. I'm just not understanding how it's not properly generating a random number.

```cpp
void randomizedQuickSort(int arr3[], int start, int end) {
    int temp, pivot;
    int s = start, e = end;
    srand(time(0)); //<------------------------ ERROR THROWN

    // Partitioning
    while (s <= e) {
        pivot = 0 + (rand() % 5);
        while (arr3[s] < pivot)
            s++;
        while (arr3[e] > pivot)
            e--;
        if (s <= e) {
            temp = arr3[s];
            arr3[s] = arr3[e];
            arr3[e] = temp;
            s++;
            e--;
        }

        // Recursion
        if (start < e)
            randomizedQuickSort(arr3, start, e);
        if (s < end)
            randomizedQuickSort(arr3, s, end);
    }
}
```

I expect the number to be between 0 and 4, but it generates -858,993,460 every time. Here's a screenshot of the error and variable values:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/47a0becfd5d26ae0a15c08af285c4357.png]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most possible issue you have is too deep recursive calls, which overflow the stack. Also you don't need that `srand()` in every recursion call. `srand()` just initializes random number generator and it usually is done once but not in every loop step. Put it outside of the `randomizedQuickSort()`. Just call `srand(time(0));` in the start of the program (or current thread if you do it in separate thread).

You have negative value for `pivot` in "Watch/Autos" Visual Studio window, because it is not initialized yet at the moment of stack overflow that interrupts program execution.

Also (as Stefan answered) you can overflow your array bounds here

```
while (arr3[s] < pivot)
    s++;
while (arr3[e] > pivot)
    e--;
```

Check `s` and `e` to be in bounds of `start` and `end`:

```
while (arr3[s] < pivot && s < end - 1)
    s++;
while (arr3[e] > pivot && e > start)
    e--;
```

Or assign `pivot` a value of a random array element between `start` and `end` instead of just random value in some range.

If you will still have stack overflow, make algorithm iterative or put less elements in the data array you sort.

Comment: Thank you. Checking s and e to be in bound stopped the overflow and the program is running. Problem is that the data isn't sorted so I've got some more thinking to do lol. Pretty sure my partition implementation just isn't correct at all.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another thing:

This:

```
pivot = 0 + (rand() % 5);
while (arr3[s] < pivot)
    s++;
```

for:

```
int arr3[] = { 1212, 1341, 61255, 1325, 125 };
```

makes `s` go out of bounds, i.e.: s will get bigger than the actual array length.

This can lead to unintended behavior.