# TicTac Game just stops randomly

Tags: c++

I wrote this Tictac game in c++... It runs fine and all except after certain number of inputs it just stops working like it goes to a new line in the compiler but sometimes i am able to complete the game.. i tried it in vscode as well as in dev c++ results are the same. is it a problem in my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class TicTac
{
    char board[3][3]={{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '}};
    int track;
    public:
        TicTac(): track (0) {}
    friend int func(TicTac);
    int display()
    {
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
        {
            for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
                cout << board[x][y]; 
                if(y<2) cout << "|";}
            cout << endl;
            if(x<2)
                    cout << "-----";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    int Pcinput()
    {   
        srand((unsigned) time(0));
        int x = (rand() % 3)+ 0;
        int y = (rand() % 3) + 0;
        if(board[x][y]=='X' || board[x][y]=='O')
            Pcinput(); 
        else {board[x][y]='O' ;
                track ++;}
    }

    int Userinput(){
        int x,y;
        cout << "Your move: \n";
        cout << "Select a row(0-2): ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Select a column(0-2): ";
        cin >> y;
        if(board[x][y]=='X' || board[x][y]=='O'){
            cout << "Select another column or row \n";
            Userinput(); }
        else {
            board[x][y]='X' ;
            track ++;}
    }

    int check()
    {   
        char y;
        if(track>=3){
            for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
            if (board[x][0] == board [x][1] && board[x][1] == board[x][2])
                y = board[x][0];
            else if(board[0][x] == board [1][x] && board[1][x] == board[2][x])
                y = board[0][x]; }
            if (board[0][0] == board [1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] || board[0][2] 
            == board [1][1]  && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
            y = board[1][1];   
        }
        if(y == 'X'){
            cout << "Player Wins";
            exit(0);}
        else if(y == 'O'){
            cout << "Pc WIns";
            exit(0);}
        else if(track==9){cout << "It's a Draw";
        exit(0);}

    }

};
int func(TicTac tr){
    return tr.track;
}

int main()
{
        TicTac mygame;

        do {
            mygame.Pcinput();
            mygame.display();
            mygame.check();
            mygame.Userinput();
            mygame.check();
        } while(func(mygame) <= 9);
}
```

Comment: Your functions are supposed to return values, but don't. See `display`, `check`, `Pcinput`, `Userinput`. Or just make them void (I think that's better.)

Comment: yeaa.... it's still the same outcome.

Comment: I think the problem is in the `time` function call in `Pcinput`. It's causing a stack overflow but I'm not sure why...

Comment: @NasratTakoor The error is explained in my answer, and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548166/srandtime0-and-rand-are-causing-a-stack-overflow-error.

Comment: Why copy your object?  Consider using reference.
from:  int func (TicTac   tr) { return tr.track; } 
to:      int func (TicTac& tr) { return tr.track; }

Or better, add new method to TicTac,  perhaps  TicTac::trackGet() { return track; }

Comment: Compiling with clang reports :  "warning: variable 'y' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience in the header `<ctime>`, but here is what I did to fix it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class TicTac
{
    char board[3][3] = { {' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '} };
    int track;
public:
    TicTac() : track(0) {
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    }
    friend int func(TicTac);
    void display()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                cout << board[x][y];
                if (y < 2) cout << "|";
            }
            cout << endl;
            if (x < 2)
                cout << "-----";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void Pcinput()
    {
        int x = (rand() % 3) + 0;
        int y = (rand() % 3) + 0;
        if (board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O')
            Pcinput();
        else {
            board[x][y] = 'O';
            track++;
        }
    }

    void Userinput() {
        int x, y;
        cout << "Your move: \n";
        cout << "Select a row(0-2): ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Select a column(0-2): ";
        cin >> y;
        if (board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') {
            cout << "Select another column or row \n";
            Userinput();
        }
        else {
            board[x][y] = 'X';
            track++;
        }
    }

    void check()
    {
        char y = '\0'; //Initialize
        if (track >= 3) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                if (board[x][0] == board[x][1] && board[x][1] == board[x][2])
                    y = board[x][0];
                else if (board[0][x] == board[1][x] && board[1][x] == board[2][x])
                    y = board[0][x];
            }
            if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] || board[0][2]
                == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
                y = board[1][1];
        }
        if (y == 'X') {
            cout << "Player Wins";
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (y == 'O') {
            cout << "Pc WIns";
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (track == 9) {
            cout << "It's a Draw";
            exit(0);
        }

    }

};
int func(TicTac tr) {
    return tr.track;
}

int main()
{
    TicTac mygame;
    do {
        mygame.Pcinput();
        mygame.display();
        mygame.check();
        mygame.Userinput();
        mygame.check();
    } while (func(mygame) <= 9);
}
```

First, as @NasratTakoor said in the comments, I changed the return type of the functions to void. Secondly, I initialized the `char` `y` with the null character (`\0`), so it would not send any errors or warnings of using "Uninitialized variable `y`". I ran the code, and it threw a stack overflow error in `time.h`, which was probably because you did this:

```
srand((unsigned)time(0));
```

The number of calls of your function was too much (as explained here: [srand(time(0)) and rand() are causing a stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548166/srandtime0-and-rand-are-causing-a-stack-overflow-error).), so I just put the `srand` in the constructor, like so:

```
    TicTac() : track(0) {
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
    }
```

Output:

```
 | |
-----
O| |
-----
 | |

Your move:
Select a row(0-2): 1
Select a column(0-2): 1
 | |O
-----
O|X|
-----
 | |

Your move:
Select a row(0-2):  0
Select a column(0-2): 0
X| |O
-----
O|X|
-----
O| |

Your move:
Select a row(0-2): 2
Select a column(0-2): 2
Player Wins
```

Comment: @AlisterXavier your welcome! Remember to accept the answer if it answered your question